# Python DataFrame - format like table

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

So guys, I have a dataframe in python looking like the first picture. Is there any way that I can format it to look like the second? I have tried using something like .groupby() but I couldn't get the desired result. I am simply looking to display that dataframe in my Jupyter Notebook in the format below.

[image: From this]

[image: To this]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but if you want to apply exact sequence of your columns,
you can try:

```
df = df.loc[:,['Dimensiuni','Algorithm','Vmin','Vmax'...etc]]
```